# How to add data to json tags MCPE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to /give a iron shovel that can break coarse dirt for my map. I tried the following command:

```
/give @a iron_shovel 1 0 {"can_destroy":{"blocks":["coarse_dirt"]}}
```

But it turns out coarse dirt is just dirt with data 1. How can I do this?

Comment: Was the slash on purposely put backward?
I have to put an answer because I don't have commenting perms.

Comment: @Eristheguest no, the slash is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Data? No.

The issue is `coarse_dirt` is not a block. Coarse dirt has the ID `dirt` and is of data `1`. There is no way to put data in can destroy/place ons so use the command:

```
/give @a iron_shovel 1 0 {"can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt"]}}
```

Unfortunately this will allow the shovel to break regular dirt and coarse dirt.

---

## *Possible* Workaround

If you are just making this for yourself and/or friends or plan on distributing a world download, you can use either of the following:

### Resource Packs

Change a rarely used block/a block that you are not using and instead of its default texture assign it to the coarse dirt's texture (don't just copy-paste the PNG file, modify the `blocks.json` so if someone has a texture pack it will look normal).

### Behaviour Packs + Resource Packs

Add an entirely new block to the game and assign the coarse dirt texture to it (don't just copy-paste the PNG file, modify the `blocks.json` so if someone has a texture pack it will look normal).

---

I won't explain how to create a resource/behaviour pack in this answer because that veers off-course from the question.

Comment: I want to allow course dirt to be broken, though. And it is "can_destroy" not "can_break"

Comment: @ZackerySpry that's not possible